# VBA Extract from Oracle

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, toad

I need to extract from a dataset in Oracle, specifically using Toad for Oracle. The following code is working but it produces a list of 10 examples of the 1 result. How do I ensure the list produces 10 examples of different variables?

```
Sub ConnectToOracle()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mtxData As Variant
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    cn.Open ( _
    "User ID = USERID" & _
    ";Password = PASSWORD" & _
    ";Data Source = DATASOURCE" & _
    ";Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle")
    
    rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    rs.Open ("select distinct var from dataset where rownum <= 10"), cn
    
    mtxData = rs.GetRows
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a10") = mtxData

End Sub
```

I have followed an initial template of code from YouTube and happy to use something else if better but I need clarification of how it should work.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "10 examples of the 1 result"

Comment: I want a list of variables that are all different in the results but it is currently giving me a list of the same value

Comment: What exactly are you doing with `mtxData` to display the values?

Comment: It is used to return the results, it was assigned as the variable to return in the example that I followed

Comment: Yes I can follow that much.  What are you *doing with it* to display the values contained in it though?

Comment: I haven't had to specify anything else, this code gave me the output, just not the output I was expecting. I'm new to using vba code so not sure what else I should add to tweak the display of values

Comment: "this code gave me the output" - that code doesn't produce any output - it runs a query and exits.  I already asked the question twice so I'll ask one last time - *how do you know what was loaded into `mtxData`* ?

Comment: I'm happy to say it again, I'm new to using vba code. Maybe I can be clearer - I don't know what you are asking, I don't understand the code, I've tried to follow multiple tutorials but it is confusing and I am unsure how to proceed. I don't know what is loaded into mtxData, is it not just the output of rs.GetRows, which is the output of my query...

Comment: What I mean is when you say "it produces a list of 10 examples of the 1 result" how *exactly* do you know that?  You load the recordset into mtxData and then the code ends.  Did you put a breakpoint on that last line and examine `mtxData` in the Watch window?  Did you do something else?  That's all I'm asking.  I'm just trying to rule out possible problems...   Maybe I can just suggest running something like `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs` to confirm the output.   What do you see in Toad if you run the same SQL?

Comment: If the problem is with the SQL then try `select * from (select distinct var  from dataset) where rownum<=10`

Comment: the result of the original code gives me the following result

426288084
426288084
426288084
426288084
426288084
426288084
426288084
426288084
426288084
426288084
                                                                                                      
where as on toad the data gives the results
423443542
423443607
423443550
423443585
423443593
426288084
423443631
423443577
423443615
423443623

Comment: What does `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J1") = mtxData` give you?  That's why I was asking how you looked at the content of `mtxData`  The `GetRows` method returns data in a 2D array, but it's flipped from what you might expect (so [0 to #cols-1 , 0 to #rows-1] not [0 to #rows-1 , 0 to #cols-1] )  `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10") = Application.Transpose(mtxData)` should also work.

Comment: I'm rusty at working with VBA but I suspect that the data returned from rs.GetRows (a 2-dimensional array) is not compatible with just setting a range equal to it, thus causing your unexpected results.